# What is the strategy by thread assignment in Kafka streams?

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am doing more less such a setup in the code:

```
// loop over the inTopicName(s) {

KStream<String, String> stringInput = kBuilder.stream( STRING_SERDE, STRING_SERDE, inTopicName );
stringInput.filter( streamFilter::passOrFilterMessages ).map( processor_i ).to( outTopicName );

// } end of loop

streams = new KafkaStreams( kBuilder, streamsConfig );
streams.cleanUp();
streams.start();
```

If there is e.g. num.stream.threads > 1, how tasks are assigned to the prepared and assigned (in the loop) threads?

I suppose (I am not sure) there is thread pool and with some kind of round-robin policy the tasks are assigned to threads, but it can be done fully dynamically in runtime or once at the beginning by creation of the filtering/mapping to structure.

Especially I am interesting in the situation when one topic is getting computing intensive tasks and other not. Is it possible that application will starve because all threads will be assigned to the processor which is time consuming.

Let's play a bit with scenario: `num.stream.threads=2`, `no. partitions=4` per topic, `no. topics=2` (huge_topic and slim_topic)
The loop in my question is done once at startup of the app. If in the loop I define 2 topics, and I know from one topic comes messages which are heavy weighted (huge_topic) and from the other comes lightweighted messsages (slim_topic).
Is it possible that both threads from num.stream.threads will be busy only with tasks which are comming from huge_topic? And messages from slimm_topic will have to wait for processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there is e.g. num.stream.threads > 1, how tasks are assigned to the
>   prepared and assigned (in the loop) threads?

Tasks are assigned to threads with the usage of a *partition grouper*. You can read about it [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#streams-developer-guide-partition-grouper). AFAIK it's called after a rebalance, so it's not a very dynamic process. That said, I'd argue that there is no option for starvation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is iteresting. What for is then *num.stream.threads* parameter, if I have e.g. 10 partitions for each topic?

Comment: You can have more than one processing thread in one app, and you can have more than one instance of your app. In the end you have the power to decide, not Kafka. More details in the Thread Modeling part of Kafka docs (Confluent one): https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html?highlight=num%20stream%20threads#threading-model

Comment: I know the page you had referenced :-). I had extended my question by adding example.

Answer (score 4):

Internally, Kafka Streams create tasks based on partitions. Going with your loop example and assume you have 3 input topics A, B, C with 2, 4, and 3 partition respectively. For this, you will get 4 task (ie, max number of partitions over all topics) with the following partition to task assignment:

- t0: A-0, B-0, C-0
- t1: A-1, B-1, C-1
- t2:        B-2, C-2
- t3:        B-3

Partitions are grouped "by number" and assigned to the corresponding task. This is determined at runtime (ie, after you call `KafakStreams#start()`) because before that, the number of partitions per topic is unknown.

**It is not recommended to mess with the partitions grouped if you don't understand all the internal details of Kafka Streams -- you can very easily break stuff!** (This interface was deprecated already and will be removed in upcoming 3.0 release.)

With regard to threads: tasks limit the number of threads. For our example, this implies that you can have max 4 thread (if you have more, those threads will be idle, as there is no task left for thread assignment). How you "distribute" those thread is up to you. You can either have 4 single threaded application instances of one single application instance with 4 thread (or anything in between).

If you have fewer tasks than threads, task will be assigned in a load balanced way, based on number of tasks (all tasks are assumed to have the same load).